# Is there a deauthorize callback for Google OAuth2?

Tags: callback, oauth-2.0

My PHP app allows user sign in via both Facebook and Google which work great, but I'd also like to know when a user revokes/deauthorizes access.

For Facebook, it's easy to specify a deauthorization callback URL under Advanced Settings which will be called by Facebook with the user's Facebook ID. For Google, I found [authentication guide](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication) which talks about revoking access but doesn't mention a callback.

How do I get Google to tell my app when a user revokes access? (i.e., by clicking a "Revoke Access" [button here](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/IssuedAuthSubTokens))

Comment: three years later - any news on this? Im having same trouble with apple and google

Answer (score -1):

There is no logout callback as such, but you may include something like

```html
<script type="text/javascript" 
    src="https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?logout&hl=en" />
```

in your logout page, to ensure the user, provided is still logged in with google, is also logged out there, when logging out of your app.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I'm asking. I don't want to know when the user logs out, and I don't think Google wants me to log the user out of Google when they leave my app. I just want to know when the user has revoked my app's privileges as a Google "third-party app with account access." Then (if the user has no other way to log into my app) I can delete the user.